# Uncaught TypeError: object is not function for dojo custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm getting the subject error when I try to instantiate a class in dojo widget I'm creating:
I have the widget and the html template for the widget in a directory called /Templates.  Here is the code:

widget (Templates/Person.js):

```
  define([
 "dojo/_base/declare",
 "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
 "dojo/text!Templates/Person.htm"
 ],
  function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, Person) {
    return
    declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: Person
    });
}
```

);

the html template (Templates/Person.htm)

```
 <div>
 <p>Bob</p>
 <p>Jones</p>
 </div>
```

The test page (TestPerson.htm)

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
<body class="claro">
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1, dojoBlankHtmlUrl: '/blank.html',
        packages: [ {
            name: 'Templates',
            location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + '/Templates'
        } ]"
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    require([
      "Templates/Person"
 ], function (Person) {
     var p = new Person();//The object is not function error occurs here
 });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?  Could it be because I'm using CDN?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine for me, are you sure the correct files are loaded (check the response in your browser console).

The only thing that you're missing is that you're instantiating the `Person` widget, but you didn't bind it to a DOM node. This is working fine for me:

```js
var p = new Person({}, "person");
```

And then I added a DOM node called:

```html
<div id="person"></div>
```

Here you can see it's just working fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/0doWDEB6C7Rbg4kU4Mtp?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a million.  I can see that it does work.  I need to keep working with the location line in TestPerson.htm:

location: location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '')